# Spawn child process escaping the quotes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to add arguments which require the string to be quoted, but `spawn` is escaping them.

Code is as follows:

```
var printProc = spawn('RawPrintServer.exe', ['STANDALONE', '"RawPrinter"'], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: ['ignore', out, err]
});
```

When I check task manager, I can see that it has spawned it as

```
RawPrintServer.exe STANDALONE "\"RawPrinter\""
```

Whereas I need

```
RawPrintServer.exe STANDALONE "RawPrinter"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `windowsVerbatimArguments`

```
var printProc = spawn('RawPrintServer.exe', ['STANDALONE', '"RawPrinter"'], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: ['ignore', out, err],
  windowsVerbatimArguments: true
});
```

Found it mentioned on a bug ([Quotes are not handled correctly when child_process.spawn() parses args](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5060#issuecomment-179488013)) but I don't think it's documented.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you need to change

```
['STANDALONE', '"RawPrinter"']
```

to

```
['STANDALONE', 'RawPrinter']
```

Comment: But then it wouldn't be wrapped in quotes, which doesn't work.

Comment: i can just guess, and what happens if you try ...,"RawPrinter"]

Comment: That isn't going to change anything, since it's just another way to interpret a string in javascript. I need the double quotes in the arguments.

Comment: hmn, if i were you i would try out everything possible f.e ..., '\"RawPrinter\"']

Comment: Tried that too. Weirdly it doesn't escape single quotes. I've managed to get hold of the source and edit the program to remove the quote requirement, thanks for the help though.